# Doctrine ORM - Calculate non-mapped property in query

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have two relevant entities - `Thread` and `Reply`, with a user able to post replies to threads.

When I return a list of thread entities using the ORM QueryBuilder I'd like to also include a boolean flag indicating whether the current user has posted a reply to that thread. Initially I thought about adding a property to the `Thread` entity and somehow setting that in a query, but it doesn't feel like the `Thread` should need to be aware of users posting replies. What is the best way to deal with this, ideally preventing the need to perform a secondary query per Thread returned?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **left join with**:

```php
$qb = $em->getRepository(Thread::class)->createQueryBuilder('a');
$qb->addSelect('count(r)');
$qb->leftJoin('a.replies', 'r' , 'WITH', 'r.user = :userId');
$qb->groupBy('a');
$qb->setParameter('userId', 8);
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Using `count(r)` you will get how many replies the user has posted per thread. You will have to loop through the result to check whether the count is > 0.

```php
foreach($result as $row) {
    $thread = $row[0];
    $hasReplied = ($row[1] > 0 ? true: false);
}
```